# Executable file to hide credentials

Tags: powershell, citrix

is there any software that can be used to pack credentials into an EXE file and hide them? The executable file should then start a PowerShell script with the stored access data.

I saw something like this 15 years ago and need it today to deploy a script via Citrix VAD.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Requests for products are off-topic, however native executable obfuscation has been a feature of AutoIT forever. There are also open source projects that provide similar functionality.  https://github.com/PELock/AutoIt-Obfuscator  https://www.pelock.com/

Answer (score 3):

> is there any software that can be used to pack credentials into an EXE file and hide them? The executable file should then start a PowerShell script with the stored access data.

If you consider this security, you're delusional. The user can easily access the content of an EXE file, either by deassembling it or using [tools such as PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/) - or running it in a debugging environment.

You should probably figure out a better way to handle credentials.

Comment: Don't answering my question

Comment: Yes, it does. It may not be an answer you like, but pointing out that your proposed solution is a very bad idea is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Might be better to restate something to the effect *"It would be delusional to consider...."* Lol

Answer (score 2):

> credentials into an EXE file and hide them ... start a PowerShell script with the stored access data.

If you're planning to "add" the credentials into the Powershell command line then you're not "hiding" anything at all.  They will still be visible to anyone with access to the server's process list.

You don't actually say what it is but, presumably, your Powershell script invokes *something* that needs these credentials.
Whatever *that* is, you need to find a [better] way of getting *it* to handle these credentials.

Comment: You don't understand the point

Comment: And what would that point be, exactly?  Please don't just restate your current train of thought - tell us what you want to /achieve/ (your desired End State) and we might be able to suggest what you actually need.